# How to find irreducible polynomial of any given degree for multiplying two polynomials?

Tags: cryptography, curve

I am working on implementing Galios Field Multiplier on FPGA. I want to implement the multiplier which can multiply for degree 163, 253, 288, 409 and 571. I have found an algorithm to implement multiplier but for testing, I need irreducible polynomial for the given degree.

The question is how to find the irreducible polynomial of the given degree. Also is there any way I can generate expected results to check if the implemented logic is correct. Like any online galios field calculator available.

I tried to search on the internet for a calculator but they are based on predefined irreducible polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

There is a technical report from HP [Table of Low-Weight Binary
Irreducible Polynomias](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf). Usually, the low-weight is preferable in Cryptography.

Also, you may look at this [Finding irreducible polynomials over GF(2) with the fewest terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/finding-irreducible-polynomials-over-gf2-with-the-fewest-terms) from math.SE to implement yourself.

You can use Maple, Mathematica, and sageMath to check your results.

The below SageMath code provides all binary irreducible polynomials for a given degree.

```
degree=4
R = GF(2)['x']
for p in R.polynomials(degree):
     if p.is_irreducible():
         print(p)
```